# Like Statement to exclude some in the sequence

Tags: sql, filter, sequence, out, filter-run-excluding

I need to run a like statement for 300 criteria and it looks like this;

[image]

how do i write a like statement excluding 112, 115, 116 ,117?

Comment: Which DB do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LIKE` here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%.112' AND col NOT LIKE '%.115' AND
      col NOT LIKE '%.116' AND col NOT LIKE '%.117';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the string after the last occurence of the dot (in your examples, there is one dot only) with `NOT IN`. The exact syntax depends on the DB, but the same idea will work on every DB.
As example for SQL Server DB, you can do this:

```
SELECT yourcolumn FROM yourtable
WHERE RIGHT(yourcolumn, CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(yourcolumn))-1) 
NOT IN (112,115,116,117);
```

See the working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1506aebc4245f32372b921f5f3335034)

In case you are not sure if the substring after the dot is numeric, quote your selection like this:

```
...NOT IN ('112','115','116','117')
```

If you need assistance how to convert this to work in another DB, please tag your DB.

Comment: Sorry I should have added more  criteria, this will be a better representation. Apologies '%K50.0%'
'%K50.01%'
'%K50.011%'
'%K50.012%'
'%K50.013%'
'%K50.014%'
'%K50.018%'
'%K50.019%'
'%K50.1%'
'%K50.11%'
'%K50.111%'
'%K50.112%'
'%K50.113%'
'%K50.114%'
'%K50.118%'
'%K50.119%'
'%K50.8%'
'%K50.81%'
'%K50.811%'
'%K50.812%'
'%K50.813%'
'%K50.814%'
'%K50.818%'
'%K50.819%'
'%K50.9%'
'%K50.91%'
'%K50.911%'
'%K50.912%'
'%K50.913%'
'%K50.914%'
'%K50.918%'
'%K50.919%'

Comment: Please add such further information to your question by editing it and do not comment answers for that. In case this leads to a complete different question (what I think could be the case here), accept a correct answer and ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) function to match the values that you don't need, hence reverse the condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE val NOT REGEXP '11[2567]'
```

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rdb6eN7CbeeDMjASLUTD93/0).

Comment: It's ok to show DB-specific options, but you should mention it. So this will work in MYSQL.